# Android force update state of headset

Tags: android, audio

In my project i use the extension cable for jack 3.5. When i disconnect headset from extenstion cable, android system doesn't send any events. How can i force update headset state?

tried this:

```
AudioDeviceInfo[] audioDevices = audioManager.getDevices(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS);
        for(AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : audioDevices){
            if(deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES
                    || deviceInfo.getType()==AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

and

```
audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn();
```

and searched required method in AOSP, but didnot find.